# How can I cause to write name of files which in a folder in python?

Tags: python-3.4

I need to write names of files in a folder. I am using Python 3.4.3 and I don't know how can I cause to write names of files in a folder

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.listdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)

From the docs:

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path...